# React native while debugging pointing issue

Tags: react-native, debugging, ios-simulator

When enabling `"Debugging"` in the ios simulator and open chrome for debugging.

The first time works perfectly but when change code and refresh automatically.

After that Debugging points somewhere else. I understand there is a mapping issue while debugging.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging mapping attached to the project when we start project or reload but at the time of `hot reloading` (auto refresh) will not update that mapping correctly.

For update the mapping correctly you have to `reload` it.

- In physical devices: Shake the device it will open a window choose 'reload' option.
- For simulator: by pressing command+R or command+control+z and choose 'reload' option.
- For emulator mac OS: by pressing r+r (2 times).

Comment: agree. is it solution to reload whole application then debugging will work properly?

Comment: Yes, Because It will remap all the code not part of the code like hot reloading do. So, Yes it will work as you expecting.

Answer (score 1):

In chrome developer tools, try switching to network tab, and check "Disable cache". It might help

Comment: Let me try and see

Comment: I always disable cache in network tab